# Snowflake - checking for pattern and returning substring within that pattern

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with multiple columns that I have to look through to check for this value: `'[m='` and return the numbers within that list.

For example lets say I have this in the 'name' column `xyzzy [m=123]`  I want to return `123`.
I was trying the below query but its not working because I keep seeing the following error:

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 3 at position 4 unexpected
> 'WHEN'. syntax error line 3 at position 34 unexpected ')'.

I also think SPLIT_PART isn't going to work because then if I have xyzzy [m=123] it will return 123] and I don't want the closing bracket included

```
case 
    WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(name, '[m=') THEN SPLIT_PART(name, '[m=', )
    WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(name2, '[m=') THEN SPLIT_PART(name2, '[m=', )
    WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(name3, '[m=') THEN SPLIT_PART(name3, '[m=', )
    WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(name4, '[m=') THEN SPLIT_PART(name4, '[m=', )
    WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(name5, '[m=') THEN SPLIT_PART(name5, '[m=', )
    WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(name6, '[m=') THEN SPLIT_PART(name6, '[m=', )
else null;


+------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+---------------+
| name         |   name2 | name3 |   name3     | name5       | name6            |
+------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+---------------+
| xyzzy [m=123]  | MyISAM |  10 | Fixed       |    0        | my comment      | 
+------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+---------------+
| rts3         | MyISAM  |    1 | test [m=122]  |    4        | my comment     |   
+------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+---------------+
| rddts3       | MyISAM  |    1  | dm32dfe     |    4        | comment [m=177]  |      
+------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+---------------+
```

*** EDIT: I've tried adjusting my query to look like this:

```
Select *,
CASE
 WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME, '(?:\[m=)') THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME, '[[]m=([0-9]+)'),
 WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME2, '(?:\[m=)') THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME2, '[[]m=([0-9]+)'),
ELSE null
END
from my_table
```

but now I'm seeing this error:
SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 0 Invalid argument types for function 'IFF': (VARCHAR(16777216), VARCHAR(16777216), NULL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `regexp_substr()` with a capture group:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(name, '[[]m=([0-9]+)', 1, 0, 'e')
```

I'm not sure what your `case` expression is for.  If you want the first match in a bunch of names, you can use:

```
COALESCE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(name, '[[]m=([0-9]+)', 1, 0, 'e'),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(name2, '[[]m=([0-9]+)', 1, 0, 'e'),
         . . .
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! @Gordon Linoff I tried this based on what you mentioned:  Select *,
case  WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME, '(?:\[m=)') THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME, '[[]m=([0-9]+)')
else null
end
from  my_table; 
but I'm seeing the error I mentioned in my question that I've added as an 'edit'

Comment: @KristiLuna . . . Run the code without the `case`.  There is no `case` expression in this answer.